Definition of integrals of simple functions on general measure

Definition: Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\psi$ a nonnegative simple function on $X$. Define the integral of $\psi$ over $X$, $\int_{X}\psi~ d\mu$, as follows: if $\psi=0$ on $X$, define $\int_X\psi ~d\mu=0$. Otherwise, let $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ be positive values taken by $\psi$ on $X$ and, for $1\leq k\leq n$, define $E_k=\{x\in X: \psi(x)=c_k\}$. Define
$$\displaystyle\int_X \psi ~d\mu=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k\cdot \mu(E_k)$$
using the convention that the right-hand side is $\infty$ if, for some $k$, $\mu(E_k)=\infty$. For a measurable, subset $E$ of $X$, the integral of $\psi$ over $E$ with respect to $\mu$ is defined to be $\int_X \psi \cdot \chi _E d\mu$ and denoted by $\int_E\psi d\mu$.

In this definition, the $E_k's$ are disjoint right?

Yes, if you allowed equalities among the $c_k$s then you wouldn't have a well-defined quantity.

If $c_i\neq c_j$ whenever $i\neq j$, then $E_i\cap E_j=\varnothing$.

The $c_i's$ are actually not assumed to be distinct but yes as @BrunoB  said since the values of $\psi$ is already laid out, if two $E_i's$ are not disjoint then $\psi$ would not be well-defined. Am I right?
